# Excel macro to change cell value when other cell in row updated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where each sheet has column E labeled "Date Modified" and column F labeled "Date Created." I want that whenever I edit a cell in columns A:D, the current date is entered into cell E of that row. If I am adding a new row, I want the current date to be entered into cell F of that row. I have the following macro saved in ThisWorkbook (and I have other Subs in there that do currently run as expected, so it's not an issue with macros being disabled or anything like that.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 MsgBox("Macro fired!")
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:D")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = Selection Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Range("F" & ThisRow) Is Nothing Then
            Range("F" & ThisRow) = Date
        Else
            Range("E" & Target.Row) = Date
        End If
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

I don't even get the MsgBox, which makes me think the `Worksheet.Change` event isn't firing for some reason. (It also still doesn't work even if I remove the `If Target = Selection` logic, which is just intended to ensure that it works on cells that *I'm* updating, not that are updated by another macro, for example. Prepending `ActiveSheet` to each `Range` makes no difference either.)

Any ideas why this macro doesn't run when I edit a cell?

Comment: And before this gets closed as a duplicate, I've looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72007609 already and I can't see any differences in formatting or syntax that would make mine fail

Comment: That sub should be in a worksheet code module.  In `ThisWorkbook` you could use `Workbook_SheetChange` to handle an update on any sheet in the workbook.  What's the purpose of `If Target = Selection Then` though ?

Comment: the code: If Range("F" & ThisRow) Is Nothing Then .... is always TRUE  because "Is Nothing"  checks the Range as object whitch always EXIST, not the Value of the Range

Comment: Re _And before this gets closed as a duplicate_.  There are significant differences between your code and the answer to that Q.  If you study it, it'll leed you to your solution.

Comment: Re _I don't even get the MsgBox_.  That suggests that at some point you've turned `Application.EnableEvents` off.

Comment: >  There are significant differences between your code and the answer to that Q. If you study it, it'll leed *[sic]* you to your solution

Thanks. Obviously the differences are that my code has a few more IF blocks, but the basic logic, `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("{RANGE}")) Is Nothing Then Range("{CELL}") = {VALUE}` is identical, hence my question. The answer, as pointed out below, would appear to be that I misunderstood where to place the code in order to make the same macro work for multiple sheets

Answer (score 0):

Since you have several sheets with the same function, you must have a code for all of them. Put the Public Sub in a module and you will call it through the Worksheet_Change of every sheet you want. If necessary, you can have different columns (not exclusively "A:D", E and F) in a sheet since these are optional parameters with default values. Try to use: Option Explicit

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub When_Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range, Optional checkColumns As String = "A:D", Optional colCreate As String = "F", Optional colUpdate As String = "E")
   Dim ws As Worksheet, targetRow As Long
   Set ws = Target.Worksheet
   If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range(checkColumns)) Is Nothing Then
      targetRow = Target.Row
      With ws.Range(colCreate & targetRow)
         If .Value = "" Then .Value = Date Else ws.Range(colUpdate & targetRow) = Date
         'use Now() if need the exact time of creation and update
         'If .Value = "" Then .Value = Now() Else ws.Range(colUpdate & targetRow) = Now()
      End With
   End If
End Sub
```

From each sheet you call it as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Call When_Worksheet_Change(Target)
End Sub
```